Nextjs getting "async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components." on server component
I'm using Nextjs v 14.1 with app router.
Inside src/app/page.tsx, I pass PostsFeed as child of ClientComponent.
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
              ...
             ....
              ....
            <section>
                <ClientComponent>
                    <PostsFeed />
                </ClientComponent>
            </section>
        </main>
    )
}

I'm following the pattern from this document, but I'm getting this error.
async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
    at PostsFeed
    at ClientComponent (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/components/ClientComponent.tsx:8:11)
    at section
    at main
    at Home

I don't understand why Nextjs thinks PostsFeed is client component.
ClientComponent.tsx
"use client";

export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return <>{children}</>;
}


PostsFeed.tsx
import { PostCard } from "./PostCard";

export const PostsFeed = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`/posts`);

  const { data } = await res.json();

  let posts = data as IPost[];

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
        <PostCard key={index} post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


If your clientComponent only receives and return a child, remove 'use client'.
The best way to use "use client" is in the specific file where you need the user to interact with it or in the file where you need to use hooks, otherwise don't use "use client".
Example "use client": "Button.js|jsx|ts|tsx".
export default function Card() {
  return (
   <article class="card">
    <div class="card__header">
   <h3>Information Header</h3>
   </div>
    <div class="card__body">
       <p>Information Body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card__footer">
        <Button /> // --> This is the client component
    </div>
  </article>
);
}

Just the button would be interactive by the user, in that file you put "use client", all the other code is server side for better optimization.
You can consult the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components

Component needs to be defined in a certain way like so:
export const PostsFeed = async () => {

should be
export default async function PostsFeed() {

